# Another solution for questions of type "circle divided into congruent arcs with n colours on each point, prove that you can create congruent k-gons"?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Here's the specific question I was looking at (USAMO 2012, q2):

A circle is divided into congruent arcs by 432 points. The points are colored in
four colors such that some 108 points are colored red, some 108 points are colored
green, some 108 points are colored blue, and the remaining 108 points are colored
yellow. Prove that one can choose three points of each color in such a way that the
four triangles formed by the chosen points of the same color are congruent.

The solutions I saw were probabilistic, but I was wondering if something like this would work?

1. If there are three of the same color sequences (like rgby) anywhere on the circle, then we can construct congruent triangles.

Proof(ish thing) of 1:
Consider the arc created between the same colors of any of the two sequences. This arc would stay constant if the points moved one unit back or forth to the next two colors along the congruent points.

As an example consider rgby -------- rgby on the circle. Connect r and r, and then move it to g and g, and the arc isolated by the line would stay constant.

2. So if we show from pigeonhole that there needs to be at least 3 of the same sequences on the 432 points, we should be done: 4! x 4 x 2 + 4 = 196 < 432.

Does this work at all?

Comment: I think you are suggesting having a sequence of four consecutive points using all four colors, where that identical sequence appears in two different places elsewhere on the circle. If that happens, yes, you have monochromatic congruent triangles. But that may not happen. Suppose all 108 red points are consecutive, then all the green ones are, etc. Then there are no four consecutive points using all colors. But there are still monochromatic congruent triangles, if you choose the "first" three points of each color. Being clear about what you need and using pigeonhole sounds hard to me!

Comment: Oh I see the issue now thank you!